# Unlimited false pages showing in Sitemap?

Tags: seo, xml, sitemap

I don’t know since when it started but today, I looked at it and it shows more than 90k pages are indexed on google in search console when my site has only 90 posts and some pages.

https://priceunder.in/sitemap.xml

Comment: I only see four pages.  Looks like you fixed it.  You can post an answer as to how in case someone else comes across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. It started around 3th 4th of January 2021 -.-
I can't find a way to remove them.
Moreover, when you search my website, it gives out a japanese result (my page is in italian).
I really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: welcome to Wordpress Stack Exchange. Consider making this a comment instead of an answer. Answers should provide solutions.